# R how to store shortest path vertices in a matrix

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path

I am new to R and I am using igraph to find shortest path given an adjacency matrix. Here is my code:

```
library(igraph)
adjmat = matrix( c(0     ,  21.6  ,     0  ,   38.46  ,   11.0 ,
                   21.6  ,     0  ,  14.5  ,       0  ,      0 , 
                   0     ,  14.5  ,  15.3  ,     8.2  ,      0 ,  
                   38.46 ,     0  ,     0  ,    15.3  ,      0 ,
                   11.0  ,     0  ,   8.2  ,       0  ,      0), 5, 5, 1);


g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjmat, weighted=TRUE)            

paths <- shortest_paths(g, 1, 4)
```

When I print `paths`, I get the following output:

```
> paths
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 4/5 vertices:
[1] 1 5 3 4


$epath
NULL

$predecessors
NULL

$inbound_edges
NULL
```

I want to store the numbers [1] 1 5 3 4 in a matrix (1 row 4 column). To my understanding, these numbers are stored in a list, so when I print paths[1], i get whole information but I only need numbers (to be stored in matrix).

Comment: Given the output, you can get those numbers with `as.numeric(paths$vpath[[1]])`. You can store that in a matrix with `matrix(as.numeric(paths$vpath[[1]]), nrow=1)`

Comment: Or `matrix(unlist(paths), nrow = 1)`, as long as there's nothing else in the object returned aside from the numbers you want.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can mark reply as answer?